# Created_at get a wrong value when I rebuild my gems . Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

My RailsGem Version is '2.3.4 ,and I builded it long before. Today I upgraded my gems system then every Model's "Create_at" displays a wrong value in Views.

The value in Mysql is right:

```
any.created_at : 2011-11-01 21:32:49
```

but in my view file:

```
<%= any.created_at %> = "Fri Mar 25 21:12:21 +0800 2011"
```

this is my gem list:

actionmailer (2.3.4)
actionpack (2.3.4)
activerecord (2.3.4)
activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.2.0)
activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter (1.2.0)
activeresource (2.3.4)
activesupport (2.3.4)
arel (2.2.1)
aws-s3 (0.6.2)

```
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.21)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
cocaine (0.2.0)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.1.2)
daemon_controller (0.2.6)
daemons (1.1.4)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.2.9)
fastthread (1.0.7)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
jdbc-mysql (5.1.13)
jquery-rails (1.0.16)
json (1.6.1)
libv8 (3.3.10.2 x86-linux)
mail (2.3.0)
mime-types (1.17.2)
mongrel (1.1.5)
mongrel_cluster (1.0.5)
mongrel_service (0.4.0)
multi_json (1.0.3)
mysql (2.8.1)
mysql2 (0.3.7)
paperclip (2.4.5)
passenger (3.0.9)
polyglot (0.3.2)
rack (1.0.1)
rack-cache (1.1)
rack-mount (0.8.3)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (2.3.4)
rake (0.8.7)
rdoc (3.11, 2.5.11)
rdoc-data (2.5.3)
rubygems-update (1.8.11)
sass (3.1.10)
sass-rails (3.1.4)
sprockets (2.0.3)
therubyracer (0.9.8)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.30)
uglifier (1.0.4)
xml-simple (1.1.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
<%= any.created_at.to_s(:db) %>
```

Comment: oh just understood it was not a question about formatting... well I guess you're just not fetching the proper record.